# How do I send midi Control Change messages

Tags: c#, midi

I am trying to send a Control Change message to a MIDI sequencer. But I really don't understand how it works.
For example what should I do in order to use the Legato pedal (n°68)? Or if I want to change the sound release time using controler n°72?

I have tried to do it like this:

```
MidiTimedMessage msg = new MidiTimedMessage();
uint releaseTimeMessage = (uint)MidiReleaseTime << 16 | (uint)72 << 8 | 0xB0;
msg.Msg = (int)releaseTimeMessage;
msg.SystemTime = sequencerService.Now;
sequencerService.PostMidiMessage(midiOutDevice, msg);
```

But it doesn't work. However, the same thing works when trying to enable the sustain pedal with this:

```
uint sustainPedalOn = (uint)127 << 16 | (uint)64 << 8 | 0xB0;
```

So I'm wondering whether there is a specific way to send and use controler such as the sound release time? Should I send a noteOn message and then send my CC message? The opposite? I have tried both... Maybe I should use something else in addition to my CC message in order to make it works?

Edit : Ok I work out the problem. It can't works because the default windows synth (Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth) doesn't handle the main part of CC messages. I have tried with an external MIDI interface and it works well.

Comment: I am using my own MIDI prototype and am developing in C#. I check whether my midi messages were good by using LoopBe1 as well as MIDI-OX. It turned out to be as good as I thought. I am wondering whether it could be the windows synth which doesn't handle some CC...